Any tricks to ease the computation for finding te extreme values for $f(x,y) = \frac{x + y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$?
My method is to directly compute the first order derivatives to find the stationary points, solving
$$
\begin{cases}
{\partial f \over \partial x}=0,\\
{\partial f \over \partial y}=0
\end{cases}
$$
gives two stationary points $({1 \over \sqrt{3}},{1 \over \sqrt{3}})$ and $(-{1 \over \sqrt{3}}, -{1 \over \sqrt{3}})$
Then I computed the second order derivatives, and used the test
$$
{\partial ^2 f \over \partial x^2}\cdot{\partial ^2 f \over \partial y^2}-({\partial^2 f \over \partial x \partial y})^2 > 0
$$
to check whether the stationary points are points where the extreme value sits.
After done the computation, my hand is sore from writing so much $xy$'s :(. Are there any tricks to compute partial derivatives for this kinds of functions? (${P(x) \over Q(x)}$, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are both polynomials and somehow the derivatives are (not fully) symmetric.)

Use symmetry of the function for the first partial derivatives, i.e, $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, and thus $f_y (x,y)=f_x(y,x)$. As for second derivatives I'm thinking about it.

here's a fancy AM-GM solution (no derivatives, no substitutions). Scroll down to the work of nguyenhuyen_AG:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1312791_maximum_value_with_2_variables

Consider the injective transformation $(x,y) = (\tan u, \tan v)$ for $u, v \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.  Then $$f(\tan u, \tan v) = \cos u \cos v \sin (u+v).$$  In the triangular region $$R = (0 \le u + v < \pi) \cap (-\pi/2 < u < \pi/2) \cap (-\pi/2 < v < \pi/2),$$ $f \ge 0$ and by the AM-GM inequality
$$f(\tan u, \tan v) \le \left(\frac{\cos u + \cos v + \sin (u+v)}{3}\right)^3$$ with equality attained when $\cos u = \cos v = \sin (u+v)$.  Hence $u = v$ and $\cos u = \sin 2u$, or $2 \sin u = 1$, giving the unique solution $(u,v) = (\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6})$ in this region $R$ at which equality is attained.  Therefore,
$$f\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}$$
is the unique maximum, and since $f(-x,-y) = -f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, this also gives us the unique minimum at $(x,y) = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$.

To address your other question, about computing the higher order partial derivatives, I would write
$$g(u,v) = f(\tan \tfrac{u}{2}, \tan \tfrac{v}{2}) = \cos \frac{u}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2} \sin\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}(\sin u + \sin v + \sin(u + v)).$$
Now the partial derivatives with respect to $u, v$ are straightforward:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} &= \frac{1}{4} ( \cos u + \cos(u+v)), \\
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u^2} &= -\frac{1}{4} (\sin u + \sin (u+v)), \\
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u \, \partial v} &= -\frac{1}{4} \sin (u+v),
\end{align}$$
and so on; the general idea being that it is easier to work in the transformed coordinate system $(u,v)$ than in $(x,y)$.

A generic strategy for these kinds of optimisations is to look for convexity and symmetry in the objective.
Notice that, for $x, y > 0$, we have that $f(x, y) > f(-x, y), f(x, -y) > f(-x, -y)$ with $f(-x, -y) = -f(x, y)$.
It follows from this that $f$ is maximised in $(0, \infty)^2$ as is minimised at the corresponding reflected point on $(-\infty, 0)^2$.
Therefore, we need only consider $f$ in the positive quadrant, where it is positive.
This is good news, because it allows us to take logs, making it much easier to deal with the quotient.
Namely, we can write
$$
\log f(x, y)
= \log(x + y) - \log(1 + x^2) - \log(1 + y^2).
$$
But now, notice that each of $\log(x + y)$, $-\log(1 + x^2)$, and $-\log(1 + y^2)$ are concave over $(0, \infty)^2$ (you can see the latter by taking second derivatives or from the fact that $L^p$ norms are log-convex).
Thus, $\log f$ is concave and symmetric, and so any stationary points must be global maximum and must lie on the line $x = y$.
It's also easy to take derivatives:
\begin{align*}
\partial_x \log f(x, y)
= \frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{2x}{1 + x^2}.
\end{align*}
Solving $\partial_x \log f(x, y) = 0$ over the line $x = y$, we have
$$
0
= \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{2x}{1 + x^2}
= \frac{1 - 3x^2}{2x(1 + x^2)},
$$
whence $x = y = 1/\sqrt{3}$.
Therefore, $f$ is maximised at $(1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})$ and minimised at $(-1/\sqrt{3}, -1/\sqrt{3})$ as you found.
